# JavaScript change css

Tags: javascript, css

```
var html = '<table style="width: 100%;border:0.5px solid white; border-spacing:0px; nth-child(even) {color:#ffffff;}"><tr style="background-color:#E9EDDB;padding-top:5px;"><td id="serNum" style="font-family:Segoe UI;font-size:16px;color:#000;text-align:center;width:5%;">' + count + '</td><td style="width: 30%; text-align: left;font-family:Segoe UI;font-size:16px;color:#000;height:auto;overflow-x:none;"><span id="taskDesc" style="">' + i.Description + '</span></td><td style="width: 8%;padding-left:5px; text-align: left;font-family:Segoe UI;font-size:16px;color:#000;"><span id="taskPriority">' + i.Priority + '</span></td><td style="width: 8%; text-align: left;font-family:Segoe UI;font-size:16px;color:#000;"><span id="taskType">' + i.Status + '</span></td><td style="width: 15%; text-align: left;font-family:Segoe UI;font-size:16px;color:#000;"><span id="taskDesc">johnsmith- ' + creatdDate + '</span></td><td style="width: 15%; text-align: left;font-family:Segoe UI;font-size:16px;color:#000;"><span style="display:none" id="taskID">' + i.ID + '</span><select id="dropDown" name="dropDown"><option value="default" SELECTED>Select</option><option value="deleteTask" >DeleteTask</option><option value="createRmndr">CreateReminder</option></select></td></tr></table>';
           items.push(html);
           count++;
```

using this lot of columns will be generated for my project i want to change odd columns color but i am unable to change it can any one tell me how to change background color for odd and even columns. I have tried this css but this property is not working in JavaScript
so please tell me how to do this ..

```
nth-child(odd)
{ 
    background:#ff0000;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to use the `!important` keyword to override the inline styles applied to the table.

```
nth-child(odd)
{ 
   background:#ff0000 !important;
}
```

This will have to be placed in a stylesheet, and **cannot be used inline**.

Answer (score 0):

```
td:nth-child(odd) {  
  color: #ccc;
}
```

From: http://css-tricks.com/how-nth-child-works/

Answer (score 0):

You must specify [nth-child](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_nth-child.asp) of what element, syntax: `element:nth-child(n) { style properties }`

```
td:nth-child(odd)
{ 
   background:#ff0000;
}
```